# Why is my button not getting grey nor with a border?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my button to get gray when I pass the cursor through it, but it does nothing, it doesnt have a border too

I tried 'gray', 'grey', 'Grey', 'Gray'

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk
def oi():
    print('oi')
def menu(cany_list):
    #some code...
    #lots of code...
    #created some frames including left
    for i in candy_list:
        i = Button(left, text=i, width = 250, activebackground = 'Gray', command = oi,  bd = 5, font =('courier', 12))
        i.pack(side=TOP)
```

i am getting a button that executes the command and has a text and the font i choosed but not a border nor a active background

Comment: what do you use: '`tkinter`, `PyQt`, `wxPython`, `PyGTK`, `Kivy` or other module ?

Comment: tkinter, thats what i imported

Comment: Please show us a complete code snippet that shows the problem. In other words, read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, your code line is missing a right parenthesis.

Comment: you didn't show full code so we don't know what you import. On Linux all buttons are gray but when I use `red` then I see it. But on some systems it may never work.

Comment: put code in question. In comment it will be unreadable.

Comment: added. filler filler filler

Comment: as I know on some system it may not work. You can try to use `ttk.Button` instead of `tkinter.Button`. OR If you have to problem to change normal `background` then you can use mouse events `Enter`, `Leave` to check normal background when you mouse hover it. GitHub: [button-hover-color](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/__button__/button-hover-color)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is to set `activebackground` of the `Button` widget, however on windows this doesn't seem to work as expected. A workaround will be  binding two events to the widget, which is `<Enter>` and `<Leave>`. In this case, it will be something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

a = tk.Button(root,text="Hover me")
a.pack()

a.bind("<Enter>",lambda e: a.config(bg="red"))
a.bind("<Leave>",lambda e: a.config(bg=root.cget('bg')))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't have to do this -- that's exactly what the `activebackground` option is for.

Comment: @BryanOakley I thought `activebackground` changes the colour only when the button is being pressed, or does it work differently when not on windows?

Comment: This is what the official documentation says: _Specifies background color to use when drawing active elements. An element (a widget or portion of a widget) is active if the mouse cursor is positioned over the element and pressing a mouse button will cause some action to occur._.

Comment: I see. I was looking into effbot and the definition is _What background color to use when the button is active_, so I was under the impression that by `active` it has to be clicked. Still, from running the actual script on windows, `activebackground` only activate when the button is actually being pressed. Hovering does not trigger the action.

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Mac do not allow to change the button background color (I think because they are created from images).

If you want to change the button background color, you can use a `ttk.Button` and change the theme for one that allows such customization, like 'clam' or 'alt'. `ttk.Button` has no `activebackground` option, the appearance is set through the style with `style.configure` for the normal appearance ('normal' state, inactive button) and `style.map` for the dynamic appearance (disabled, active, ...).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('clam')  # change theme
# set active color to gray for the button with style 'gray.TButton', 
# if you want it to apply to all buttons, change it to 'TButton' 
style.map('gray.TButton', background=[('active', 'gray')]) 
ttk.Button(root, text='Ok', style='gray.TButton').pack()

root.mainloop()
```